# Unity Преследование объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сотни раз проделывал это действие, но в этот раз ничего не работает почему то.

```
// Оба объекта находятся в одном локальном пространстве !

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (target != null) {
            Vector3 move = target.localPosition; // Преследуемая позиция...
            print(move); // move = 6.0, -5.2
            // по факту же движется вообще в обратную сторону в бесконечность
            rbObj.AddForce(move * accel * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Получается, что в Transform в отличии от RectTransform строит координатные оси от центра объекта а не от родительского. Следовательно чтобы объект преследовал другой объект необходимо получить разницу между целевым объектом и текущим.

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (target != null) {
            Vector3 move = target.localPosition - transform.localPosition;
            rbObj.AddForce(move * accel * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
```